# How to remove Hetrogenius elements in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a column named as the country

```
country 
A
B
C
D
A,B
D,A
```

I want to make a new entry of each mixed row like

```
country 
A
B
C
D
A
B
D
A
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: ``df.country.str.split(",").explode()``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"country":["A","B","C","D","A,B","D,A"]})

df.country.str.split(",").explode().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.chain` in order to chain the values:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

# return a list from series of comma-separated strings
def chainer(s):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(s.str.split(',')))

df = pd.DataFrame({"country":["A","B","C","D","A,B","D,A"]})   
    
# create a new dataframe, chaining as appropriate
res = pd.DataFrame({'country': chainer(df['country'])})
 
print(res)
```